# Javascript Grammer: how to assign correct values to an array of objects

Tags: javascript

let's look at the code:

```
  Test() {
let array1 = new Array(5).fill({ a: 0 })
let array2 = new Array(5).fill({ a: 0 })
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    array1[i].a = i
    array2[i] = {a:i}
    console.warn("array = ", array1)
    console.warn("array2 = ", array2)
  }, 0.2 * i)
}
```

}

In this case, I wanna assign a series of values to the array1 & array2, and there are two ways to do it, which lead to totally different results.
In the case `array1[i].a = i`, after all the code is ran, the result is array =  `[{a:4},{a:4},{a:4},{a:4},{a:4}]`, which is not what i wanted.
In the second case `array2[i] = {a:i}`, the result will be `[{a:0},{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},{a:4}]` as expected.
I wanna know why is it like this? What's the machanics behind this phenomenon？

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `.fill()` and pass an object, you assign **the exact same object** to every element of the array. Thus, modifying a property at one array index modifies the same property at all the other indexes, because they're all pointing to the same thing.

There are a variety of ways around this issue. You could fill the array with `0` or `null` or some dummy value and then iterate through with `.forEach()`, or more simply just use an indexed `for` loop to initialize each element. If you initialize with `{ a: 0}` in a `for` loop, a new object will be created on each iteration.

Comment: This isn't a "grammar" issue, by the way.